# Why do we write $+C$ on only the right-hand side of an equation in differential equations?

Tags: integration, differential

Suppose we have a separable differential equation and the last form of the equation is:

$$3y^2 \, \mathrm dy = x \, \mathrm dx$$

After solving the equation, why do we write $+C$ to only right-hand side of the equation and not the left one? As far as I can see solution set is changing depends on it.

Comment: Both sides have a constant of integration.  When you bring over both constants to one side, it's just one new combined constant.
$$C_1-C_2=C$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for your MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs. `$3y^2dy = xdx$` shows up as $3y^2dy = xdx$

Comment: Well I know about bringing two constants to one side but if we suppose all constants at right side of the equation final form will be +C and with the other way final form of the equation will be -C and answer will change for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both integrations yield constants.  Technically the integration should look like:

$$\int3y^2\, \text{d}y = \int x\,\text{d}x \\
y^3 + C_1 = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C_2
$$

To simplify, we just move the constants together, by subtracting $C_1$ from both sides, yielding:

$$y^3 = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C_2 - C_1$$

Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are both unknown constants, their subtraction will also result in an unknown constant.  So we simply set $C = C_2 - C_1$, and get:

$$y^3 = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C$$

Remember, $C$ is an unknown constant, and can be positive or negative.  Therefore, putting $+C$ on the right-hand side is equivalent to putting $+C$ on the left-hand side.  It just changes *what* the constant is, which doesn't matter, since we don't know it anyway.  If it were on the left, we would just change the definition of $C$ to be $C = C_1 - C_2$.  Again, it doesn't matter because it is unknown.  As long as there is a single definition for it, you can put it on whatever side you want.